# Converting pandas strings column to datetime with ocassionally missing hour part

Tags: python, pandas, data-munging

I have duration string noted as '48m 37s' and sometimes as '1h 38m 29s' and a collection of string that holds this data in pandas dataframe's column

I'm trying to convert datatype of duration column to datetime as follows

```
pd.to_datetime(usg['duration'], format='%Hh %Mm %Ss')
```

but failing with the following error

```
ValueError: time data '1h 38m 29s' does not match format '%Mm %Ss' (match)
```

I understand that sometimes the hour part is missing in the list entries of duration column and wondering if there is a way to specify multiple formats if in case one fails to match other succeeds.

Doing so shall yield the output as below preserving the order of entries in the column

```
     00:39:40
     01:38:29
     07:39:40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use: `pd.to_timedelta(usg['duration'])`

```
usg = pd.DataFrame({'duration': ['48m 37s', '1h 38m 29s']})

pd.to_timedelta(usg['duration'])
```

gives the output:

```
0   00:48:37
1   01:38:29
Name: duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This will fail on the OP's sample data, also don't post a code snippet as this isn't useful for others. You should post a complete code example that demonstrates that this works for the OP

Comment: This does not fail.

Comment: Sorry I had missing `s` in my data, the point remains, please don't post short code snippets, answers should be complete with sample data, code and produced output as currently it looks like a comment

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
usg = pd.DataFrame({'duration':['7h 39m 40s','15h 39m 40s','39m 40s']})
print (usg)


usg['duration'] = np.where(usg.duration.str.contains('h'), 
                pd.to_datetime(usg['duration'], format='%Hh %Mm %Ss', errors='coerce'),
                pd.to_datetime(usg['duration'], format='%Mm %Ss',errors='coerce'))
print (usg)
             duration
0 1900-01-01 07:39:40
1 1900-01-01 15:39:40
2 1900-01-01 00:39:40
```

Another solution:

```
usg['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(usg['duration'].where(usg.duration.str.contains('h'), 
                                 '0h '+ usg['duration']),format='%Hh %Mm %Ss')
print (usg)
             duration
0 1900-01-01 07:39:40
1 1900-01-01 15:39:40
2 1900-01-01 00:39:40
```

---

```
usg.loc[~usg.duration.str.contains('h'), 'duration'] = '0h '+ usg['duration']
usg['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(usg['duration'], format='%Hh %Mm %Ss')
print (usg)
             duration
0 1900-01-01 07:39:40
1 1900-01-01 15:39:40
2 1900-01-01 00:39:40
```